# Reading .qm translation files with Java

Tags: java, qt, internationalization

I'm trying to read a .qm translation files with Java.
.qm files are binary files. I don't have access to the .ts files.
And I don't find much info on these .qm files.
How are they structured ?
Regards,

Comment: If you are using Java together with a Qt c++ project (i.e. Android), the easiest solution would be to use JNI to call c++ methods to do the translations. If thats the case I can show an example.

Comment: The app is Java Swing app. I would only read (and use) the .qm file. No other interaction is foreseen. But why not JNI. Why not JNA ? Your examples would be greatly apprecied.

Answer (score 0):

There's no documentation that I know of, but if you look at [`QTranslator::load`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qtranslator.cpp.html#_ZN11QTranslator4loadEPKhiRK7QString) you should be able to follow the format of the QM file.

You will probably need to reimplement `QTranslator` in Java, as you need not only the ability to load the files, but also to extract and apply translations in Qt fashion.

Comment: I dig into that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As per request of OP:

You could use those files by using the Qt libraries and JNI. By using the translator in a c++ dll you can translate strings easily. However, you cannot extract the files or list the contained translations. But if all you need is the actual translation, this solution should work.

I cannot give  a real example, because I only now how it works in theory, I haven't tried it, because it's not trivial. But if you are eager to try it out, the general idea would be:

1. Create a C++ dll and build it against QtCore. The easiest way is to download Qt from their website [qt.io](https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/). You can for example create a default library project with QtCreator. **Note:** Besides Qt5Core.dll, Qt requires other libraries to correctly run. They are all included in the installation, but once you deploy your application, those of course have to be includes as well.
2. Include JNI to the C++ project and link against it. if you're new to this, here is a nice tutorial: [Java Programming Tutorial](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html)
3. Create your wrapper methods. Methods in cpp you can call from java that take java strings, convert them to QString, translate them with QTranslator and convert them back.
4. Load the library in Java and execute those methods

**Important:**
First, I don't know how java handles dll dependencies. If you encounter errors while loading the dll, it's probably because dependencies of your dll are not present. Second, Qt typically requires a `QCoreApplication` running in the main thread for most of it's operations. I tested the translator without such an app, and it worked. So apparently for translations only the app is not required. However, depending on what you do in your dll, I think this is important to know.

If you need more details, feel free to ask.

Comment: Building the whole JNI rapper is quite a hell, especially when you are not (as I am) familiar with C++ and qt. Building the whole JNI rapper is quite a hell. Building it from scratch is a bit overkill for I would like to do.  Thanks any way. I'll have a try at reading the file directly in Java..